# CBOR implementation produces error on PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php, cbor

I am using [CBOR](http://cbor.io/) for packing data in my C applications and PHP scripts. For PHP, I've downloaded [implementation](https://github.com/2tvenom/CBOREncode) from the site above. It works good at PHP 5.4.23, but on PHP 5.3.3 including CBOREncoder.php produces an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html1/......./CBOREncoder.php on line 15
```

This is beginning of CBOREncoder.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * CBOR encoder/decoder
 *
 * http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7049
 * http://habrahabr.ru/post/208690/ thx man :)
 *
 * Class CBOREncoder
 */
class CBOREncoder
{
    const
        MAJOR_OFFSET = 5,
        HEADER_WIPE = 0b00011111, <-- this line produces error
        ADDITIONAL_WIPE = 0b11100000,
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is PHP 5.3.x does not support binary numbers. That was included in PHP 5.4.

From php website: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

> Binary number format has been added, e.g. 0b001001101.

So, CBOR does not support PHP 5.3